# Trying to learn more about SQL and need held understanding existing code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to learn more about SQL and I would like to understand what an existing piece of code does.

The code is below:

```
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[USPS_LOAD_RPT_ORG_HIERARCHY]
@USER_ID = N'HVT',
@OPER_BUS_SEG_CD = N'APA'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

`DECLARE @return_value int` creates an empty variable named `@return_value` of the datatype `int` (`int` is a range of non-fractional numbers between `+-2,147,483,648`)

For reference, `DECLARE @return_value int = 8` would assign the variable a value of `8`.  Without the value assigning the variable is empty, or `@return_value = NULL`

The next step:

```
EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[USPS_LOAD_RPT_ORG_HIERARCHY]
@USER_ID = N'HVT',
@OPER_BUS_SEG_CD = N'APA'
```

... executes a procedure `[dbo].[USPS_LOAD_RPT_ORG_HIERARCHY]` and also feeds that procedure two parameter values `@USER_ID = N'HVT', @OPER_BUS_SEG_CD = N'APA'`.  This procedure outputs a value, which is then stored in `@return_value`.

The best way to understand that section would be to look through the stored procedure and see what it does.  Those parameter values are most likely used as variable filters within the procedure, ie: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE userID = @USER_ID`

`SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value` selects/displays the returned value with the column alias 'Return Value':

```
Return Value
   12345     --Or whatever @return_value is
```

A more common way to write that would be:

```
SELECT @return_value as [Return Value]
```

Comment: I highly recommend against using `'single quotes'` to delimit an identifier. Ideally you would avoid keywords, reserved words, and spaces, but if you must have a name that violates [the rules for identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers), you should use `[square brackets]`. Single quotes are deprecated in some cases and, even when they're not, make an identifier easily confused with a string literal.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You know, I almost edited that in after answering, then decided there wasn't enough harm in using single quotes and it may just distract from the rest of the answer.  But you're very correct and I should have included that.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

it just returns scalar value from `USPS_LOAD_RPT_ORG_HIERARCHY` function.

```
@USER_ID = N'HVT',
@OPER_BUS_SEG_CD = N'APA'
```

are not used.

So the result will be

```
Return Value ...
```

where dots will be replaced by actual result